# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled not working in one of my Activities but everywhere else it does work

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

For some reason this doesn't work in one of my activities but everywhere else it works fine when i press the back arrow in the toolbar it goes back to my MainActivity.

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

//Initializing toolbar
mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

if((getSupportActionBar() != null)){
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.equalizerTitle);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_home_up);
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity
     android:name=".activities.EqualizerActivity"
     android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

**EDIT**

This activity uses a constraint layout as parent but i don't see why this would be the cause, all other activities use RelativeLayout and there they work fine.

Comment: Do you have some back button / home button listeners on that activity? You may have forgotten to add super() call there to handle the button.

Comment: @Gaket Already found the issue, in all other activities i do not implement the override method onOptionsItemSelected but in this activity i do because i have other button in my toolbar, after removing this method it works but how can i keep this method and make the back button work because now my other buttons dont work.

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll write the answer

Comment: Wrote a detailed answer. Please, let me know if you still have questions or feel free to upvote / mark as resolved if it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to handle menu buttons. The issue is that the "back" button is also kind of a menu button.

In order for Android to know that you don't have a specific handler for the button and it should be handled by the framework, you need to let Android know it via returning `false` when you don't "consume" the event. According to the docs:

[onOptionsItemSelected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29)

> boolean Return false to allow normal menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here.

So, you should have smth like this:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
               case YOUR_BUTTON:
                   // do something
                   return true;
       }
       // By default, allow Android to work on it
       return false;
```